# How can I populate a select field based on the choice of it's foreign key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Basically I have this situation.

Models -
Employer, EmployerContact

EmployerContact is a foreignkey to Employer.

In my form, I want to choose the employer, then dynamically populate the select field of EmployerContact with only contacts for the chosen Employer ONLY.

Right now it shows all EmployerContacts from all Employers.

I've found a couple of solutions but they seem sketchy... Could someone walk me through this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bit more of your code for better understanding of the problem. As far as I understand, you want the detail page of employer to show the contact associated with it.

In Html you can add

```
{% for contact in employer.employercontact.all %} 
/* here employercontact is the objectname that I have assumed, you can edit accordingly */
       {{ contact.employer_contact }}
{% empty %}
        <p> No contacts </p>
{% endfor %}
```

In urls.py

```
path('employer/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

In views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
      model = Employer
      template_name = 'add your template name'
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I apologize for not being clear enough with my question. 
I think what I am trying to do is easily solved with some javascript to dynamically populate a select field with EmployerContact objects based on the Employer choice. I've solved it for now by implementing a multiple step form...choose the employer on step 1, then choose the contacts on step 2...and so on.